# How to pick 64 colors that work in harmony?

Tags: color

I have an application which requires 64 distinct colors that need to look good together.

I've found some resources online that use a color wheel. They allow you enter a color and then they show a list of colors that are complimentary. For instance, I can choose "tetradic colors" and I now have 4 colors that look good together.

How do I do this for 64 colors? I'm not simply looking for shades of a single color, but rather colors that span the spectrum that also look good together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large color palette generator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119019/large-color-palette-generator) Or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137438/where-to-find-or-how-to-make-large-harmonious-color-palettes

Comment: 64 different colors is *a lot*. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/xFppKUk.png) are 64 colors with saturation = 0.5, lightness = 0.5 and hue equally distributed from 0 to 360 (this could be done in several ways). It's almost impossible to distinguishing these colors from their neighbors. And since they are spread out across the whole color circle they don't really have a particular "expression". It's just "all colors". I think you need to allow for different shades of each hue. If you chose 4 shades of each hue it would reduce the hue number to 16. Still would be hard to distinguish though.

Comment: Its not possible to generate that many distict colors that a human could call distinct But you can try https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/

Comment: Try providing more details about *why* you might need all those distinct colors, you might get some useful answers, even if they might not address your primary question. Or you could directly ask a new question on how to reduce the number of colors you need, though that might be more suitable for the UX stack.
Also, consider [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114699/how-many-different-colours-can-i-have-in-a-data-visualisation) about distinguishing with colors.

Comment: @joojaa Yes! Exactly what I need.

Comment: @J.E Why I need 64 colors: I'm putting together a game with 64 pieces which will be put together in random ways where the pieces are next to each other. So the colors will need to look good together. I'd like them to be distinct colors so that they'll be easily picked out from a pile. Do they have to be so distinct that someone can tell them all apart - probably not, but it's a good thing to aspire to.